# Differences in Windows and Mac OS X IO, performance tuning in 2015?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, performance, cross-platform

Experienced Mac / OS X Developer here, working with libCinder, a cross platform C++ toolkit for graphics, looking for some guidance on optimizing Windows disk access.

I am in the process of optimizing disk access for reading (large, high resolution) image sequences. Ive implemented my optimizations on my Mac running OS X 10.10, and have almost quadrupled my disk performance to match synthetic disk benchmarks (yay).

Testing the same code on Windows results in no performance increases (boo!)

I want to explain what I am doing and why, and what little I understand.

Current state of my code:

My code has 4 threads:

- Main thread spools up OpenGL and Renders, handles events etc.
- Thread 1 reads from disk and loads my images directly into memory from their disk representations (tiff header and all) and dumps into a concurrent circular buffer of cinder buffer objects. (Producer).
- Thread 2 reads from my circular buffer of buffers (Consumer) and 'decodes' them to raw cinder surface objects (uncompressed image data), and adds them to a second Concurrent Circular Buffer of surfaces (Producer)
- Thread 3 reads from my Surface buffer and submits to a secondary GL context as textures, and notifies main there is a new texture available.

I separated my threads out this way from measuring performance and hotspots, indicating disk access + file decoding was a limiting factor, and by uncoupling them I was able to make gains.

Now, within Thread 1, which does the disk reads, I've tried a few different methods of disk access:

- Using library provided disk access (Mac + Win) via ci::DataSourcePath
- fread (Mac + Win),
- CreateFile (Win Only)
- mmap (Mac only for now)

On OS X, I see that using fread (with no cache and read-ahead flags via fcntl) results in slightly better sustained disk read performance that using Cinders provided ci::DataSourcePath object, but not by much. I am able to almost saturate my Mac Book Pro's SSD's read getting roughly 750MB/s via both methods. Interestingly memory mapped file access (with madvise) was not as fast (400-500MB/s), but thats why we benchmark.

On Windows, CreateFile, fread (with no flags for no cache available to my knowledge) and ci::DataSourcePath all result in similar performance, however, its 200MB/s, and on my hardware it should be possible to get near 8GB/s (yes, seriously, we have raided Intel PCI SSDs).

That is dismal!

Some questions for folks more familiar than I with Windows disk IO:

- Research indicates that FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFER + FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED for Windows CreateFile was (is?) the way to go.
- Other info indicate I should be using IOCompletionPorts and async IO.
- Is Boost::ASIO viable for high performance, unbuffered disk access? Most posts indicate it being used for socket stuff.

I'd like to avoid too much cross platform complexity (overlapped and async IO seems non trivial), and it seems crazy to me that the exact same x64 architectures result in such drastically different performance. What am I missing - why doesnt my decoupling work on Windows? What API should I be using in 2015?

Any advice is very appreciated.

TL;DR - Experienced Mac dev tried some basic optimizations for cross platform disk IO and failed when it comes to Windows, Windows IO is weird, what API should I be using in 2015 to get fast disk reads on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: I/O completion ports aren't relevant here - they're only useful when you're dealing with a large number of distinct I/O streams, typically a TCP/IP server.  All the third-party / standard methods will be calling ReadFile at the end of the day, so you may as well just use it directly, at least for experimental purposes.  How big a read are you performing at a time?  Are you sure that the Windows machine is actually capable of the performance you're expecting?  (There might be a problem with the device drivers, for example.)

Comment: Random thought: it might be worth trying zeroing out the buffer(s) before starting the I/O, to make sure all the memory pages are ready to go, and perhaps call VirtualLock too.  (Swapping might be throwing off your timings.)  Also, are you testing the I/O code independently of the rest of the program?  If there's some sort of unexpected interaction between the threads, that could also be throwing off your timings.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the thoughtful feedback.

I guess I didn't realize other implementations would be using ReadFile, but that makes some sense.

I am profiling thread IO on windows via Process Explorer and Resource Monitor.

The disk is capable of roughly 8GB/s via synthetic benchmarks, this disk in questions is 4x Intel NVMe's PCI SSDs striped together.

Reads are for the entire full file size, so anywhere from 20MB to 100MB depending on the sequence of files I am loading. 

I can turn off other threads and have, to isolate any thread contention or locking issues, and i get the similar perf

Comment: How much CPU is Windows using during the read operation?  If you run multiple processes at once (on different files) do they each get 200MB/s, or 200MB/s total, or somewhere inbetween?  (And I don't suppose you have access to the source code for the benchmarking software you're using?  Because it sounds like it's doing something right!)  Are you using hardware or software RAID?

Comment: Harry - great idea about the source code and multiple app runs - should have thought of that myself! For the benchmarking suite. Turns out its available (CrystalMark), and they are using a MS tool called DiskSpd - and it looks like that is doing overlapped IO and ReadFile/CreateFile, using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFER. This looks like a great set of code to look over. Very very useful.

Multiple apps runs net me burst 1.2GB/s reads, running a few instances of my app, and ~900 sustained. Interesting.

Comment: Theoretically I don't see why overlapped I/O would be significantly faster than synchronous I/O - there might be some additional overhead per request, but that shouldn't make much odds.  But that's not a guarantee, it would certainly be worth trying.  There is a significant per-file overhead in Windows, though I don't quite see how that could account for the figures you're getting; nearly an extra half a second for a 100MB file seems far too much.  If that is the problem, though, you probably don't need multiple processes per se, you just need to be reading multiple files at once.  Good luck!

Comment: (Don't forget to also try preallocating, zeroing, and locking the buffers.  Oh, and if overlapped I/O does help, look into ReadFileGather, it might be faster than plain ReadFile.)